# Spark is not defined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, laravel-spark, laravel-5.5

I using spark in laravel with vue.js. I add  in home.blade.php and I got this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Spark is not defined
```

what I had done:

```
php artisan spark:install
```

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include the script variables for spark

```
<script>
    window.Spark = @json(array_merge(Spark::scriptVariables(), []));
</script>
```

In your `<head></head>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to either install the Spark Installer or install via Composer before you can use `php artisan spark` commands.

See installation info at https://spark.laravel.com/docs/5.0/installation#installation